# When should std::map / std::set be used rather than std::unordered_map / std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, stdmap

The C++11 standard introduced `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set`, which use a **hash** function and have (on average) constant complexity of inserting/deleting/getting the elements.

In cases where we do not need to iterate over the collection in a particular order, it seems there is no reason to use "old" `std::map` or `std::set`.

Are there some other cases / reasons when `std::map` or `std::set` would be a better choice? Would they be for example less memory consuming, or is the ordering their only advantage over the "unordered" versions?

Comment: FWIW, don't use the standard provided unordered containers.  They are basically required to be a vector of linked lists.  There are better open source hash based containers out there.  My advice is only use `std::map`/`std::set` if you need to maintain a sorted order.  Otherwise use a hash based container.

Comment: The advantage of the ordered map/set is that they're ordered. That's really the only reason I can think of to use them.

Comment: @NathanOliver the "better" hashmaps out there (like absl for instance) are better for many uses, but not all. I tried replacing unordered_set/map with those alternatives in our library, in some places it was a nice gain, in half of the places it was a catastrophic loss.

Comment: @Johy The simple answer is that for every use when you need performance, use what's cache friendly, in this case `unordered_map` and `unordered_set`. Keep in mind though that if you use these structures for *buffers* and try to access them from multithreaded context you may experience hiccups, since occasionally the underlaying array will have to grow (same is true for `list` vs `vector`). In essence, benchmark and profile before you make final decision.

Comment: @NathanOliver from my experience with the most popular implementation of `robin hood` and `hopscotch` from either `tessil`, `abseil` and `skarupke` they just don't work with anything other than simple types. If you even need to store `smart pointers` the performance will just tank down, and with bad `hash function` some of them will simply give up and crash or run out of memory. So I would recommend benchmarking before deciding to use anything other than `std`.

Comment: " and have in average constant complexity of inserting/deleting/getting the elements" This is theoretical complexity. Realtime/Accidental complexity is another topic... One reason why many developers often prefer vectors for smaller data sets instead of sets/maps even if the latter would better fit in terms of abstract semantics in doubt.

Answer (score 3):

They are ordered, and writing `<` is easier than writing hash and equality.

Never underestimate ease of use, because 90% of your code has trivial impact on your code's performance.  Making the 10% faster can use time you would have spent on writing a hash for yet another type.

OTOH, a good hash combiner is write once, and get-state-as-tie makes `<`, `==` and `hash` nearly free.

Splicing guarantees between containers with node based operations may be better, as splicing into a hash map isn't free like a good ordered container splice.  But I am uncertain.

Finally the iterator invalidation guarantees differ.  Blindly replacing a mature tested moew with an unordered meow could create bugs.  And maybe the invalidation features of maps are worth it to you.

Comment: "a good hash combiner is write once, and **get-state-as-tie makes <, == and hash nearly free**. " Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @John Sure.  Can you please explain what of that bolded text you understand or recognize?  Do you know what `std::tie` is?  `==`, and how it relates to `std::tie`?  Ditto with `<`?  What a hash combiner looks like?  How a hash combiner and `std::tie` might be related?  (Yes or no to any of these questions is reasonable, but I have no idea what you know so I don't know what to explain)

Answer (score 1):

`std::set/std::map` and `std::unordered_set/std::unordered_map` are used in very different problem areas and are not replaceable by each other.

1. `std::set/std::map` are used where problem is moving around the order of elements and element access is O(log n) time in average case is acceptable. By using `std::set/std::map` other information can also be retrieved for example to find number of elements greater than given element.
2. `std::unordered_set/std::unordered_map` are used where elements access has to be in O(1) time complexity in average case and order is not important, for example if you want to keep elements of integer key in `std::vector`, it means `vec[10] = 10` but that is not practical approach because if keys drastically very, for example one key is `20` and other is `50000` then keeping only two values a `std::vector` of size `50001` have to be allocated and if you use `std::set/std::map` then element access complexity is O(log n) not O(1). In this problem `std::unordered_set/std::unordered_map` is used and it offers O(1) constant time complexity in average case by using `hashing` without allocating a large space.